# html numeric keyboard plus comma sign

Tags: html, mobile, numeric-keypad

I've got an input that holds a valuta number.
With `<input pattern="[0-9]*" />` **I was able to force the numeric keyboard to show up on mobile phones. But I want to add the option to select a comma, preferably in the empty bottom left corner.**

Is this at all possible?
If this need a javascript or jquery solution, that's ok.

I've tried:

```
<input type="number" id="valuta" pattern="[0-9,]*" placeholder="0,00" step="0.01" />
<input type="text" id="valuta" pattern="[0-9,]*" placeholder="0,00" />
<input type="tel" id="valuta" pattern="[0-9,]*" placeholder="0,00" />
```

And some other input values for `pattern` I can't recall.

Comment: @pandorym nope, because in the post I say I was able to force the numeric keyboard.. with just HTML, no jQuery. But I want to add a comma. Can't find any similar posts.

Comment: Comma doesn't come under numeric keypad. You **have** to use text pad and use JavaScript to block out others.

Comment: So not at all possible. Using text pad is not an option I'm afraid. Thank you for the answer

Comment: No buddy, when you trigger the num pad on the devices, it doesn't actually allow input for `,`.